# Different Content-Types on the same route with Serverless Next JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, next.js, serverless, vercel

I'm wondering if the following scenario is possible with serverless (deployed on Vercel) Next JS:

I have a route `/product/[id].tsx` when you send a request with the header `Accept: text/html`, I would like it to go through the normal Next JS flow with a React page. But, when a request is given with `Accept: application/json`, I would like it to return the JSON representation.

I have accomplished it by using some custom middleware I wrote for Express (see below), but I would also like to deploy it on Vercel, and Vercel is not designed to work with a custom Express implementation.

So the question is, is it possible to do this in a serverless environment? Could one of the Next JS React pages return pure JSON, or could you return React from a Next JS Api route? Or is there another way to accomplish this?

server.ts

```js
import express, { Request, Response } from "express";
import next from 'next'
import { parse } from 'url'

const port = parseInt(process.env.PORT || "3000", 10);
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";

async function run(): Promise<void> {
  const app = express();
  const nextApp = next({ dev })
  const nextHandler = nextApp.getRequestHandler()
  await nextApp.prepare()

  app.use((req, res) => {
    res.format({
      "text/html": async (req, res) => {
        const parsedUrl = parse(req.url!, true)
        await this.handler(req, res, parsedUrl)
      },
      "application/json": async (req, res) => {
        res.json({
          "dummy": "data"
        })
      }
    })
  });

  app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(
      `> Server listening at http://localhost:${port} as ${
        dev ? "development" : process.env.NODE_ENV
      }`
    );
  });
}

run()
```

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to @timneutkens (Lead engineer for NextJS) on Twitter we have our answer. It is possible. You use `getServerSideProps` and perform everything you want to the `res` object there. Just be sure to end it with `.end` so it skips the react rendering phase.

I've made a sample repo for the code here: https://github.com/jaxoncreed/nextjs-content-type-test

And here's the page that matters:

```js
import Head from 'next/head'

export default function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="container">
      <Head>
        <title>Create Next App</title>
        <link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" />
      </Head>

      <main>
        <h1>Test App</h1>
      </main>

      
    </div>
  )
}

export async function getServerSideProps({ req, res }) {
  if (req.headers.accept === "application/json") {
    res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json')
    res.write(JSON.stringify({ "dummy": "data" }))
    res.end()
  }
  return {
    props: {}, // will be passed to the page component as props
  }
}
```

Comment: This is phenomenal. I was able to use this with the `feed` package to make a fully custom RSS feed. Nice trick.